# NuxtPage vs slot for Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

What is the difference between these two `components` in `Nuxt3` and how do I use them correctly?

If I want to use `pages/...` what is the right approach here to create links and jump from page to page?

Answer (score 3):

Everything is pretty much explained in the documentation: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/migration/pages-and-layouts/

You need to use this in `app.vue`

```html
<template>
  <nuxt-layout>
    <nuxt-page /> <!-- used to display the nested pages -->
  </nuxt-layout>
</template>
```

With a default `/layouts/default.vue` file

```html
<template>
  <div>
    this is coming from the layout
    <slot /> <!-- required here only -->
  </div>
</template>
```

You will get this on `/` (with `/pages/index.vue`)

```html
<template>
  <div>index page</div>
</template>
```

[image]

And with the following structure, you will achieve dynamic pages

[image]

`/pages/users/index.vue`

```html
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: false
});

function goToDynamicUser() {
  return navigateTo({
    name: 'users-id',
    params: {
      id: 23
    }
  })
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <p>
      index page
    </p>
    <button @click="goToDynamicUser">navigate to user 23</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

`/pages/users/[id].vue`

```html
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: false
});

const route = useRoute()
</script>

<template>
  <pre>{{ route.params.id }}</pre>
</template>
```

I've removed the layout here to show how to disable it, but you can totally let the default here or even provide a [custom one](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/layouts/#example-setting-the-layout-with-pages).

---

So, `nuxt-page` is to be used when you want to display the pages in your app (replacing `<nuxt />` and `<nuxt-child />`) while `<slot />` is to be used in the layout (as any other component using the [`slot` tag](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html)).

Comment: I got confused by this because the Nuxt Docs for Components https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components/ shows the V2 usage.
Tells me I need be careful in the docs and check what it says - a documentation switch like in VueJS Docs would be really great.
https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-5 has a switch for API Preference

Comment: @user1864957 the documentation will be merged for less confusion as [explained here](https://nuxt.com/vision-2023).